# Read .sql database stored in the disk as a file, in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin

I use `nodeJS` and npm package [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) to read sql databases from the server. You know, the typical usage:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
});

//implicit connection and then query
connection.query('SELECT 1', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results)
});
```

But now I need to run some tests locally on some virtual machines, and I want to read the data from a sql database **stored as a `.sql` file**. This sql file was exported with `phpmyadmin`

[image]

How can I read from a sql database whose data is stored in the disk as a .sql file, said file exported via phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the file as a database.  (Although that would be a cool project for somebody to create.)

The .sql file is just an export which contains actual sql statements one after another, which can be used to re-create a database by "importing".

My recommendation is to install mysql-server locally, import what you have, and connect to localhost 3306.

Comment: phpmyadmin also exports to JSON. Is there any simple way of doing it?

Comment: @Thanks, is there any other method? JSON for example?